# Randomly increase ID with Doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine

My entity momentary uses this annotation for it's ID:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;
```

I need to generate an ID, but I want to represent the last inserted one increased by a **random** value.

Comment: take a look [at this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/doctrine-user/GxXAO3-g4vo) about add a custom generated value strategy

Answer (score 0):

Try this: (Sequences are supported by Oracle, PostgreSql and SQL Anywhere)

```
 /**
 * @Id
 * @GeneratedValue(strategy="SEQUENCE")
 * @SequenceGenerator(sequenceName="message_seq", initialValue=1, allocationSize=100)
 */
```

OR

```
/**
* @Id
* @GeneratedValue(strategy="UUID")
*/
```